# How to get percentage of different shipment mode in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I get percent off different Ship Mode?

```
df3.groupby('Ship Mode')['Ship Mode'].count()
```

[image: My o/p]
[image: My database]

Comment: Could you have a look at the answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df3.groupby('Ship Mode')['Ship Mode'].count() / len(df3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
df3['Ship Mode'].value_counts(normalize=True)
```

Use Value counts and pass normalization.

Value Counts: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html

Answer (score 0):

```
df3.groupby('Ship Mode')['Ship Mode'].count()/df3.shape[0]
```

Comment: Could you explain this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272).